# Reshaping data frame from lists to longitudinal data in R

Tags: r, reshape, longitudinal

I am trying to reshape the data I have in a data frame for longitudinal analysis. First, here's a reproducible example (albeit not the most elegant one, I am still learning):

```
# reproducible example
time <- c(199801, 199802)
id <- list(jan=c("Allianz", "Adidas", "Continental"), feb=c("Allianz", "Adidas", "BMW", "Continental"))
indeg <- list(jan=c(0,0,1), feb=c(0,0,2,4))
example <- data.frame(time = unique(time))
example$id <- id
example$indeg <- indeg
example$dax <- c(1,0)
```

As you can see, I have unique time points (time), one variable that will remain true for all observations (dax) and then some I need to somehow "unlist" (id and indeg). In reality, the data features 180 time points and a few more variables in the same format. This is what I want the data to look like later:

```
time2 <- c(199801, 199801, 199801, 199802, 199802, 199802, 199802)
example2 <- data.frame(time2)
example2$id <- c("Allianz", "Adidas", "Continental", "Allianz", "Adidas", "BMW", "Continental")
example2$indeg <- c(0,0,1,0,0,2,4)
example2$dax <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
```

I have looked into the `untable` and `reshape` function of R, but did not really understand how to use them on my data. It seems that part of the solution would be to flatten the lists by using `example$id <- vapply(example$id, paste, collapse = ", ", character(1L))` before reshaping?

As I'm both new to longitudinal analysis and relatively new to R, I regularly find myself stuck with these seemingly trivial procedures. Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I know there have been numerous questions about reshaping, but I could not find any that deal with lists in rows (perhaps because I'm not too familiar with the terminologies yet).

Comment: `tidyr::unnest(example)`

Comment: Thank you, Sotos, this works perfectly fine for the example. Unfortunately it seems that my example did not do my data justice as I get the error "# Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements." (for flattened lists) or "Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [ID, indegree,outdegree,constraint,closeness]" for the vectors. It looks like tidyr might still be what I am looking for, so off to troubleshooting for now.

Comment: I got it to work using `sumarTable.unnest <- unnest(sumarTable, sumarTable$ID, sumarTable$indegree, sumarTable$outdegree, sumarTable$constraint, sumarTable$closeness, .drop = NA, .id = NULL, .sep = NULL)`. Thank you so much for your help, greatly appreciated!